# Implementing a hidden segment control in UITableView

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiscrollview

I want to put a hidden segment control on the top of UITableView, like search bar in iBooks. Then I found [Creating a hidden UISegmentedControl in a UITableView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11976176/creating-a-hidden-uisegmentedcontrol-in-a-uitableview). By implementing `UIScrollViewDelegate` methods:

```
- (void)scrollViewWillBeginDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
```

I can show and hide the hidden segment control. But this segment control cannot respond to touches. Just the tableview cover the top area again, like the original post.

So I want to known how to make the segment control can react to touch. I found something like:

```
scrollView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
scrollView.canCancelContentTouches = NO;
scrollView.delaysContentTouches = NO;
```

but didn't work.(I use `self.tableView.userInteraction...`)

Anyone give me a hand?

Comment: Does the 'scrollViewDidScroll' fire?

Comment: @gran33 YES. I just make UITableViewController conform to UISCrollViewDelegate, then all scrollViewXXX methods get called.