# Swift: Hide and Show UISegmentedControl in UICollectionView when scrolling

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, uisegmentedcontrol

I need to hide my `UISegmentedControl` in my `UICollectionView` when the collection is scrolling. Below my snippet code :

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

.....
.....
if (collectionViewMovie.contentOffset.y > 100) {
        self.segmentedControl.isHidden = true
    } else if (collectionViewMovie.contentOffset.y < 100) {
        self.segmentedControl.isHidden = false
    }
}
```

Its work to hide when the collection is scrolling. But sometimes the segmented is not show when I scroll slowly to the top. Its not smooth too when hidden the UISegmentedControl. I [read](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11976176/creating-a-hidden-uisegmentedcontrol-in-a-uitableview) this but its on Objective C. I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31928394/ios-swift-hide-show-uitabbarcontroller-when-scrolling-down-up) to but its on UIScrollView. Any suggest and answer will help for me. Thanks in Advance

*Edit

```
 func scrollViewWillBeginDragging(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    if scrollView.panGestureRecognizer.translation(in: self.view).y < 0 {
        self.segmentedControl.isHidden = true
    } else {
    self.segmentedControl.isHidden = false
    }
}
```

Now its always show or hide when scrolling even smooth scroll, but there is stil no animation. Thanks again in advance

Comment: `UICollectionView` is a subclass of `UIScrollView` so you could use the `UIScrollView` property `isDragging` to set your segmented control's `isHidden` property. You could also use the `UIScrollViewDelegate` methods `scrollViewWillBeginDragging` and `scrollViewWillEndDragging` to show/hide your segemented control.

Comment: @DennisW. so i must create a `UIScrollView` programaticaly at `viewDidLoad`? But i think it will be weird because the `UICollectionView` has own `Scroll` . Its make me confuse -.- Sorry im new in swift (for 4 month)

Comment: No, a `UICollectionView` is a type of `UIScrollView` ( see  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inheritance_(object-oriented_programming)). You can just make your collection view conform to the `UIScrollViewDelegate` protocol to have access to the methods I mentioned. You already have access to the `isDragging ` property.

Comment: @DennisW. oh i see, i will try it tonight. I will give the result ASAP. Thanks for your suggest

Comment: @DennisW. I read the site that you recomended for me. With some modificationi its working in my case now. You can accept its as answer so I can mark as accpept answer